# Efeitos de paginação com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Alguém sabe me responder como fazer efeitos de paginação me minha pagina HTML? Por exemplo eu tenho uma tabela mas essa tabela só pode exibir 10 registros por vez, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso usando angularjs ou jquery?

Comment: Para AngularJS eu já usei ng-table, tem também ng-grid, é só procurar

Comment: Valeu cara obrigado, eu procurei mas não achei, você sabe me dizer como eu acesso o this no angular?, exemplo eu clico no botão e chamo uma função que faz referencia a esse botão usando o this, como eu faria isso com angularjs?

Comment: Você pode usar ng-click, e chamar o método, procura "Crud angularjs" que irá encontrar alguns exemplos de cadastros.

Comment: RECOMENDO:
**Angular UI Bootstrap - Pagination Directive** *Exemplo:* http://plnkr.co/edit/6PFCPuFrN6lfGHjHVwGf?p=preview *Confira:* http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ *CÓDIGO COMPLETO:* https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination *Outra recomendação:* https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Comment: Acho isso pode ajudar. Simple table with pagination
http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1

Answer (score 2):

Leonardo, segue o exemplo abaixo que implementei em cima da diretiva DirPagination:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7kscCEXOFNBk4MTrnwcS?p=preview

A única alteração que fiz foi adicionar o arquivo animated.css ao header, logo, adicionei a classe de animação ao ngRepeat ( no caso Dir-Pagination ), sendo assim qualquer filtro, ou paginação, voce tera o efeito:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" />

<li class="animated fadeIn" dir-paginate="meal in meals | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ meal }}</li>
```

Ou seja, não foi necessário utilizar nada alem de css para o efeito.

Segue o site caso queira utilizar outras animações:

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/